My GE range Model #JBSddDMcWW made a loud POP, then smoke. Now, broil and bake both out. Do I just need a broil elem. or more?
MY GE range Model# JBS55Dn2WW made a loud POP. Some black smoke came from the rear of the unit.  Wires at the broiler element connection are burned.  Only the broiler was on.
Now the broil element and bake element don't work.  The control panel and cook top both are working.
Do I need just a broiler element, or something more?
Please help!

You'll probably have to take it apart (disconnected from the wall first) and give some pictures to see what actually happened.  It'd be tough to recommend specifically what to do with the limited information here.

Agreed, you need a repairman (or need to be a repairman) to find what shorted out and why. Personally I would not try to use it until it's fixed; catastrophic failure like this could be actively unsafe.

I would open the breaker at once and not return power until assessed by repair person.  You don't know what may have fried besides what you saw, e.g., a feed wire on backside may have melted and be dangling where it could arc to the chassis.  That you haven't already opened the back leads me to suspect your wisdom would lead you to a pro  to handle this.

Could be something else. I had wire come loose from element, shorted. Control board still had display, but no output voltage to oven elements.
